# best option to put Nginx logs into Kafka?

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka

We are dealing with large log files from several servers that we add on HDFS. We currently have a good, batch solution (mainly moving and writing the files each day), and want to implement a realtime solution with Kafka.

Basically, we need to put the logs from Nginx into Kafka, then write a consumer to write on HDFS (this could be done with the HDFS consumer https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/contrib/hadoop-consumer).

Which approach would you recommend to move logs into Kafka ?

- We could write a nginx module, but it isn't that simple. This https://github.com/DemandCube/Sparkngin could give some clues.
- Reading the logfiles (tail ...) looks like a bad idea as there is a useless write operation. Logstash would also require write/read operations before pushing to Kafka, which seems unnecessary.

any other idea ?

Comment: It has been several months since this question was asked. Have you discovered any possible answers?

Comment: @spuder : we implemented a tail -f producer. It's actually quite light in terms of ressources, almost no development and quite robust (just need to take care of logrotate). I'm actually not sure to change that anytime soon.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question. But recently, I need to also do the same thing.

The problem of `tail -f producer` is on log rotation and when tail dies, you don't really know which lines has been sent to Kafka.

As of nginx 1.7.1, access_log directive can log to syslog. Please see http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html. We leverage that to log to rsyslog and from rsyslog to Kafka. http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omkafka.html

It's a little round-about way to doing it, but this way, there's <s>no</s> less chance for logs to be missing. Also if you're using CentOS, rsyslog comes with it standard anyway.

So in short, here's the setup I feel best option to put nginx log to kafka:

> nginx -> rsyslog -> kafka

Comment: nginx write access log to syslog, does this write to disk.
If it can write to rsyslog via tcp, I think the performance will much better than writing disk.

Comment: Look at nginx syslof config linked on my answer. You can specify server IP address or unix socket. So from nginx side, it should not write to disk. From syslog side, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Try `tail -F` (capital F) -- I wouldn't use it for production purposes, but when I saw your comment, I felt it would be good to mention this little tidbit of goodness.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try linux pipes **tail+[kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat)**.

Read messages from stdin, produce to 'syslog' topic with snappy compression

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog | kafkacat -b mybroker -t syslog -z snappy
```

Be careful to use -F instead of -f,   -F is able to handle **log rotation problem**.
-F keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessible; useful when following by name.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried using [`Logstash`](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash) for this purpose? It works fine in our systems.

`Logstash` is a component that you just need to unzip and to configure some small parameters like `Kafka` end point and port, topic and the format that you want to transfer the message and from what file.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Nginx-Clojure](https://github.com/nginx-clojure/nginx-clojure) Java log handler to save nginx access log to kafka in real time. In the below example we use java to write nginx access log to a file in real time.

nginx.conf :

```
location /hello {
  ....
  log_handler_type java;
  log_handler_name mytest.MyLogHandler;
  log_handler_property logUserAgent on;
}
```

Java code :

```
public class SimpleLogHandler implements NginxJavaRingHandler, Configurable {

    boolean logUserAgent;

    @Override
    public Object[] invoke(Map<String, Object> request) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("logs/SimpleLogHandler.log");
        NginxJavaRequest r = (NginxJavaRequest) request;
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
            String msg = String.format("%s - %s [%s] \"%s\" %s \"%s\" %s %s\n", r.getVariable("remote_addr"),
                    r.getVariable("remote_user", "x"), r.getVariable("time_local"), r.getVariable("request"),
                    r.getVariable("status"), r.getVariable("body_bytes_sent"), r.getVariable("http_referer", "x"),
                    logUserAgent ? r.getVariable("http_user_agent") : "-");
            out.write(msg.getBytes("utf8"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void config(Map<String, String> properties) {
        logUserAgent = "on".equalsIgnoreCase(properties.get("logUserAgent"));
    }


    @Override
    public String[] variablesNeedPrefetch() {
        return new String[] { "remote_addr", "remote_user", "time_local", "request", "status", "body_bytes_sent",
                "http_referer", "http_user_agent" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this thread as I was working for nginx logpush to kafka. After reading, I found it very useful. Specially the comment from "maresa". Exactly this should be the best way using rsyslog.

But at the same time, I personally think, logstash can not be a good fit in this pipeline where kafka is being used. At least I did not find any rationale behind this to use logstash where kafka is being used to process the log. It would make more sense to me using logstash without kafka in this pipeline if were to use logstash.

Thanks anyway. Great thread. Appreciate anybody share more thoughts on it.

Reg, Amin